How to identify whether rows within a group have values in the same columns?
I have a dataframe where each row represents the ratings a project group received from one of three raters (advisor, mentor, other). The columns titled ELA1, ELA2, MATH1, MATH2, ESS1, ESS2 are the items groups can be rated on. However, each group only needs to be rated on three of these items, which means each group can be rated on a different set items. But all three raters should rate the same items within a group. I want to check whether all three raters rated the same set of items within a group. It would be ideal to create a dummy variable that indicates whether the group received ratings on the same set of items from each rater.
Below is an example of my data frame:
df <- data.frame(group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 rater=c("Advisor", "Mentor", "Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", "Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", "Other"),
                 ELA1=c(1, 2, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 ELA2=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 MATH1=c(3, 3, 2, NA, 2, NA, 3, 3, 2),
                 MATH2=c(2, 3, 2, NA, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1),
                 ESS1=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 1),
                 ESS2=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA))

In the example data frame above, there are two groups (group A and C) that are scored on the same items by all three judges. But the ratings provided by each rater to group B were not for the same set of items. I need help figuring out how to write code that will identify instances when each rater did not rate the same set of skills within a group and ideally create an indicator column that indicates whether a group's raters rated the same set of items or not.
I have no code to add below because I don't have a clue about how to approach this at all. Is there anyway to get r to do this?

Here's another answer that is maybe less elegant but possibly simpler to digest. It makes use of the colSums function.
df <- data.frame(group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 rater=c("Advisor", "Mentor", "Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", "Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", "Other"),
                 ELA1=c(1, 2, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 ELA2=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 MATH1=c(3, 3, 2, NA, 2, NA, 3, 3, 2),
                 MATH2=c(2, 3, 2, NA, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1),
                 ESS1=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 1),
                 ESS2=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA))

groups <- df$"group"
raters <- df$"rater"

same_rating_set <- c()

for (group in groups) {
    group_ratings <- list()
    for (rater in raters) {
        # Dataframe that just has the entries for a single group/rater combo
        rater_df <- df[df$"group" == group & df$"rater" == rater, ]
        # Ignore the "group" and "rater" columns in checks
        rater_df <- rater_df[, !colnames(rater_df) %in% c("group", "rater")]
        # Running `colSums` on a single-row data.frame essentially flags which
        # columns have a missing value
        missing_columns <- colSums(is.na(rater_df))
        # Just keep the column names for non-missing columns
        rated_items <- colnames(rater_df[, !missing_columns])
        # Add the current rater's rated items to our main list
        group_ratings[[length(group_ratings) + 1]] <- rated_items
    }
    # Group ratings now has 3 values, each corresponding to the set of items
    # that each rater gave the group. If across those 3 sets there is only 1
    # unique set, it means the three sets were identical (i.e. the raters all
    # rated the same items).
    same_rating_set <- c(same_rating_set, length(unique(group_ratings)) == 1)
}

df$"same_rating_set" <- same_rating_set


This worked! for some reason, I had to drop the unique() function when creating the groups and raters strings in order for the loop to work. But once I did that, it worked perfectly. Thank you!!

Ah, you're right, my original answer was formatting the results for (A, B, C) rather than (A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C) like your question needed. Updated it now. No problem!

You can check per group, whether all of the columns have "is the number of na values 0 or n()":
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(Flag = if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(is.na(.)) %in% c(0, n())), .by = group)

#  group   rater ELA1 ELA2 MATH1 MATH2 ESS1 ESS2  Flag
#1     A Advisor    1   NA     3     2   NA   NA  TRUE
#2     A  Mentor    2   NA     3     3   NA   NA  TRUE
#3     A   Other    2   NA     2     2   NA   NA  TRUE
#4     B Advisor   NA    2    NA    NA    2    2 FALSE
#5     B  Mentor   NA   NA     2    NA    2    2 FALSE
#6     B   Other    1    1    NA     1   NA   NA FALSE
#7     C Advisor   NA   NA     3     3    3   NA  TRUE
#8     C  Mentor   NA   NA     3     3    3   NA  TRUE
#9     C   Other   NA   NA     2     1    1   NA  TRUE

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), rater = c("Advisor", "Mentor", "Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", 
"Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", "Other"), ELA1 = c(1, 2, 2, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), ELA2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA
), MATH1 = c(3, 3, 2, NA, 2, NA, 3, 3, 2), MATH2 = c(2, 3, 2, 
NA, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1), ESS1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 1), 
    ESS2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))


first you need a summary table of which items had non blank reviews by group then you can convert that to indicator and add the summary table to the main table.
I did this with two separate summarize() but they could be combined into one. Its just so you can see the separate steps of the transformation.
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 rater=c("Advisor", "Mentor", "Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", "Other", "Advisor", "Mentor", "Other"),
                 ELA1=c(1, 2, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 ELA2=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 MATH1=c(3, 3, 2, NA, 2, NA, 3, 3, 2),
                 MATH2=c(2, 3, 2, NA, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1),
                 ESS1=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 1),
                 ESS2=c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA))

# create summary table of to show by group which products had non-blank reviews
summary_tbl <- 
  df |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  
  summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric),\(x) sum(is.na(x)),.names = "{.col}_indicator")
    ,.groups = "keep"
  ) |> 
  summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric),\(x) if_else(x==0,1,0))
  )

 # join it with original table
df |> 
  left_join(
    summary_tbl
    ,by=join_by(group)
  )


A pivot_longer solution. It checks the number of unique items per group (must be 3):
library(tidyverse)

my_output <- my_df %>% 
  left_join(
    pivot_longer(., cols = matches("\\d$"), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
      summarise(.by = c(group), flag = n_distinct(name) == 3),
    by = "group")

Output:
> my_output
# A tibble: 9 × 9
  group rater    ELA1  ELA2 MATH1 MATH2  ESS1  ESS2 flag 
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1 A     Advisor     1    NA     3     2    NA    NA TRUE 
2 A     Mentor      2    NA     3     3    NA    NA TRUE 
3 A     Other       2    NA     2     2    NA    NA TRUE 
4 B     Advisor    NA     2    NA    NA     2     2 FALSE
5 B     Mentor     NA    NA     2    NA     2     2 FALSE
6 B     Other       1     1    NA     1    NA    NA FALSE
7 C     Advisor    NA    NA     3     3     3    NA TRUE 
8 C     Mentor     NA    NA     3     3     3    NA TRUE 
9 C     Other      NA    NA     2     1     1    NA TRUE 

If you remove the comparison ... == 3 and leave only n_distinct(name), it will give the number of items. I think it's useful too.
Edit
An alternative rowwise take and identifying the rated items with cur_column.
my_other_output <- my_df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(rated_items = str_flatten_comma(
    across(matches("\\d$"), \(x) if_else(!is.na(x), cur_column(), NA)),
    na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  mutate(.by = group, .before = rated_items, same_items = n_distinct(rated_items) == 1)

Output:
> my_other_output
# A tibble: 9 × 10
  group rater    ELA1  ELA2 MATH1 MATH2  ESS1  ESS2 same_items rated_items       
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>      <chr>             
1 A     Advisor     1    NA     3     2    NA    NA TRUE       ELA1, MATH1, MATH2
2 A     Mentor      2    NA     3     3    NA    NA TRUE       ELA1, MATH1, MATH2
3 A     Other       2    NA     2     2    NA    NA TRUE       ELA1, MATH1, MATH2
4 B     Advisor    NA     2    NA    NA     2     2 FALSE      ELA2, ESS1, ESS2  
5 B     Mentor     NA    NA     2    NA     2     2 FALSE      MATH1, ESS1, ESS2 
6 B     Other       1     1    NA     1    NA    NA FALSE      ELA1, ELA2, MATH2 
7 C     Advisor    NA    NA     3     3     3    NA TRUE       MATH1, MATH2, ESS1
8 C     Mentor     NA    NA     3     3     3    NA TRUE       MATH1, MATH2, ESS1
9 C     Other      NA    NA     2     1     1    NA TRUE       MATH1, MATH2, ESS1

Created on 2024-05-19 with reprex v2.1.0
